# Bose QC35 schematics

Tags: surface-mount, headphones

I'am looking for the schematics of the Bose QC35 headphone.

I need to replace the 2.5mm jack on the pcb but I don't find any schematics or SMD part number on the web.

[image: Text]

These part looks pretty similar except the outer gold ring that may not fit once the covers are back in place

https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/670/sj2_2551x_smt-1779161.pdf

If anyone have some data to share it will be really appreciated.

Comment: Asking for accents is off topic, component identification questions are not, but you need to provide dimensions

Comment: Most name-brand products use custom parts.  If this is a custom part, the only repair source would be another unit.

Comment: Closest I could find is [this](https://www.kycon.com/Pub_Eng_Draw/STX-25406-4N-TR.pdf). The "L" pad is in the wrong place (comes out the end rather than the sides, but might be useable with a bit of adaption).

Comment: I think most home repairers would be fine with any part that *works* even if it looks a little ugly. If the part you use doesn't line up with the PCB footprint, you could use jumper wires to attach the part to the PCB, then put it on the PCB upside down so the pins don't contact the pads directly, and stick it there with hot glue... that's possibly what I would do.

Comment: I would open that jack up and ensure I understood what each pin does.  They may be internally switched.  I.e. what you find that "looks like" is not necessary "works like".